# How to show single colorbar in loop by Python?

Tags: python, for-loop, matplotlib, python-3.7, colorbar

I've tried to plot images of my loaded 2D data (512x512 pixels) in a loop by matplotlib with Python3. But it turns out to show weird images with multiple colorbars. Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import sys
import os
from load_images import load, File
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm

arr_spe = [x for x in os.listdir() if x.endswith(".SPE")]

for x in arr_spe:
    try:
        dat = load(x)

        plt.imshow(dat,cmap=cm.jet, vmax = 2000)
        plt.colorbar()
        plt.savefig(x[:-4]+'.png', dpi=500, bbox_inches='tight')
    except ValueError as error: 
        print('ValueError(empty)-'+x)
```

I use the code to load my data in the following link: [Reading SPE file from CCD camera](https://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/Reading_SPE_files.html) by naming the code as load_images.py.

And I got many images like
[image: Results after running this code]

Does anybody have ideas to solve this issue? Just simply show single colorbar in an image

Comment: Try and move the plt.colorbar() line outside of the for loop at the end.

Comment: sorry I didn't provide enough details. @TrentonMcKinney, thanks for your help! Your suggestion works!